# Preventing idling - ideas to keep warm in a car when the engine is off and it is cold outside

Tags: transport, cars, pollution, air-pollution

I have asked a few people whose cars are idling if they mind switching them off to reduce pollution.  One response I get from quite a lot of people is that they need to keep the car running to enable the heating to work, otherwise they will get cold.

Considering taxi drivers, those sitting in their car during lunch hours, those waiting and all other people; what ways can you keep warm inside a car without idling and without using the internal heater?

Comment: Please edit your question to give a maximum time and minimum outside temperature (define 'cold'). Half an hour or two hours makes quite a difference. So does 0C or -10 C

Answer (score 2):

1. Wear a woolen underlayer (woolen socks + woolen long sleeve t-shirt + woolen long pants)
2. Wear warm clothes (hat, snood, scarf, warm jumpers, warm trousers)
3. Wear winter driving gloves (or any warm gloves)
4. Drink hot drinks
5. Keep a flask of hot water in the car
6. Buy an in-car kettle (charged
   from cigarette lighter)
7. Heated car seat cover
8. Warm blankets (wool is
   usually best)
9. Heated car blanket (charged from cigarette lighter)
10. <s>Keep the heater on</s>
11. Fit a dedicated heater to run off the fuel system

Comment: I wonder about the efficiency of using the cigarette lighter. Its power comes from the car's battery which is recharged when driving, so basically you are still using fossil fuels to get warm. Doesn't that defeat your purpose?

Comment: @THelper battery charging efficiency will be much greater when driving than when idling.

Comment: @THelper also you're heating the person who needs to be heated, rather than heating the entire engine, cooling system etc. just to collect some small amount of that heat and use it to warm a poorly insulated cabin with lots of windows.  You can draw up to about 150W from the lighter socket (don't do that for too long or you'll flatten the battery) while even idling an engine burns a few kW of fuel.

Comment: The engine block will stay warm for some time after turning off the engine. If you leave the fans running on low it should help keep you warm. I haven't tried this myself but I imagine it would be sufficient for 30 minutes or so, depending on how cold it is outside.

Comment: @LShaver thanks, I had not considered that option, really good idea (obvious really!)

Comment: @LShaver Running the heater with the engine off will provide warm air for a couple of minutes at most. The engine block will retain heat for quite some time, but that heat isn't available unless coolant is being circulated.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to fit a [dedicated heater](https://www.eberspacher.com/products/fuel-operated-heaters.html) run off the fuel system.  This is a much more efficient way of turning fuel into cabin heat.  They're common in motorhomes in a form that directly heats the cabin air by burning diesel, but in smaller vehicles they work with the existing fans and heater block.  Either way they have their own exhaust system.

Yes, they burn fossil fuels, but they do this in an optimised way, which uses a lot less fuel compared to running an engine to produce heat.

(I've linked to a leading brand, as their website is more informative than anything else I could find)

Comment: For petrol engines it is a much more efficient way. For diesel engines it is a "hmmmaybe".

Comment: @Stian, why's that? Diesel heaters for motorhomes and some work vehicles were where this started, because they use so much less fuel than heating via the engine

Comment: Because of the compression ratio and the rotating flywheel mass diesel engines use very little fuel when idling, and it is common enough to just let the engine run over night when it gets cold enough. But yeah, a heater is a good answer - for petrol engines it is clearly the better choice, and for some diesel engines it is.

Comment: @Stian [figures from 2015](https://www.energy.gov/eere/vehicles/fact-861-february-23-2015-idle-fuel-consumption-selected-gasoline-and-diesel-vehicles) say otherwise for cars, and even if there's been a revolution in fuel economy since then, most cars on the road are older than that.  For that much fuel you'd get [4kW from a diesel heater](https://www.eberspacher.com/fileadmin/data/countrysites/EB_UK/images/technical_images_ebuk/tech_airtronic_ebuk/airtronic_D4_table_ebuk.jpg) which is several times what you'd need to warm a car cabin.

Comment: ... Delivery trucks use so much more at idle than cars that keeping a cab warm would use 30x as much fuel using the engine at idle compared to a dedicated heater. (900W should be enough). Figures from links in my previous comment. I'll probably expand this worked example into my answer, when I'm at a pc

Comment: Chris yes, there are certainly examples of diesel cars where the calculation is net positive - I am for instance not saying that a delivery truck, or for that matter, an 18 wheeler is going to be cheap to run overnight. I am saying that many diesel cars are cheaper and easier to warm with idle - considering the investment cost of the heater. You even get the added bonus of driving a fully warmed up engine, which decreases wear and increases efficiency.

Comment: Those are averages. If you pick and choose carefully you can find cases where it's not too bad, but you'll always do better burning fuel in a system designed to put heat where it's needed than relying on the waste heat of an unnecessary process. As for wear, idling is bad for engines, so that doesn't help. Overnight isn't the subject of the question, so I won't address that